# Could anyone give me an example of non-smooth strong convex function?

Tags: convex-optimization

Could anyone give me an example of non-smooth strong convex function? I cannot figure out one.

Comment: Please make the question body self-contained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$x\mapsto|x|+x^2{}{}{}{}{}{}$$